# Is there anyway to do sth like MPI_BARRIER in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-computing

When doing distributed async training, it needs get all workers waiting at some time to sync the model params, for example, sync once an epoch is finished and calculate the auc on validation set.

MPI_BARRIER is good enough when using MPI, is there anything similar in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

You could use shared counter variables to implement a barrier. IE, following 3.6.4 from the [Little Book of Semaphores](http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/LittleBookOfSemaphores.pdf) you could do something like this

```
 # N is number of workers
 def barrier():
    sess.run(counter_adder_ops[0])
    while sess.run(counter_vars[0]) % N != 0:
      time.sleep(FLAGS.sleep_interval)
    sess.run(counter_adder_ops[1])
    while sess.run(counter_vars[1]) % N != 0:
      time.sleep(FLAGS.sleep_interval)
```

during training

```
for i in range(FLAGS.iters):
        barrier()
        sess.run(sync_op)
        barrier()
        old_val, updated_val = sess.run([local_param_var, train_op])
```

Here's a full [example](https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/ef407a599f0f549f62d91c3a00dcfb6c)
 that runs through synchronized training loop locally

Comment: thanks very much !!! I try this approach and it works well when all worker is on the same machine. But it hangs when I start 2 nodes, each with a worker and a ps. Usually it takes about 20 minutes or more for one barrier() call. Do you have any idea to fix this?

Comment: Haven't tested this on more than one machine. Does it actually succeed after 20 minutes? How long does a single sess.run call take to increment on ps? (is your network slow?) Which part does it hang on?

Comment: Yes it succeed after 20 minutes. It just hangs on the sess.run(counter_add).

Comment: I've tried multi-machine with some simple DNN, works well. I am wondering if there's some dead-lock when multi-machine is accessing the same variable?

Comment: Do you have more concurrent runs than you have op threads? (defaults to number of cores). You could try increasing `config=tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=..)` for your ` `tf.train.Server(config=config)` -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4455